# Angular 6: Property Binding Inside [innerHtml]

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In one of the component, I need to generate a few lines of HTML from a function and inject this into the view. I'm able to inject it using [innerHtml]. However,  there is ***n*** number of select tags which I need to bind it and send back the data.

None of the answers did help me achieve this

```
// component.ts

export class FillInTheBlanksComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() config: object;

  public renderedBody: any;

  constructor(
    public sanitizer: DomSanitizer
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.replace();
  }

  replace(): void {
    let getSelectOptions = async (options, template_string) => {
      var html = ''
      for(const option of options) {
        html = await html + `<option value="${ option }">${ option }</option>`
      }

      this.renderedBody = this.renderedBody.replace(template_string, html);
    }

    let loop = async (options) => {
      this.renderedBody = this.config['details'].description;

      for(const option of options) {
        await (
          this.renderedBody = this.renderedBody.replace(
            option.template_string, 
          `<select>${ option.template_string }</select>`
        ));

        await getSelectOptions(option.values, option.template_string);

      }

      this.renderedBody = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.renderedBody);
    }

    loop(this.config['details'].options)
  }

}
```

My HTML file

```
<div class="fill-in-the-blanks">
    <div class="header">
        <h6>{{ config['details'].title }}</h6>
    </div>

    <div class="body">
        <p [innerHtml]="renderedBody" #p></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there any alternative way to achieve this?

Comment: If I am understanding you problem correctly your best bet is to use reactive forms to databind dynamic select tags

Comment: I get a template like this - `hello %option1%` I need to replace `%option1%` with a select tag, will the reactive forms work in this case?

Comment: see this: https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-formarray-dynamic-fields/

Comment: Nope, this won't work based on my working experience with reactive forms. Thanks!

Comment: Your code is definitely hacky and very far from best practice. Are you loading the options from a server? Can you explain why this should not work? In my experience this also works for async loaded things, you just need to use the appropriate methods and operators like async pipe. You shouldprobably go back to learning the basic templates and directives for angular

Comment: You should go ahead and write interfaces for your configs, no need to use bracket notation. Then you can use the Save Navigation Operator to deal with async data in the template https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#safe-navigation-operator. Then you can preload and use *ngFor

Comment: rendering HTML in the component code is also generally a no-go and should be prevented

Comment: The paragraph is custom and select tag can appear anywhere inside it. I use interfaces, bracket notation is only till I achieve the goal.

Comment: I agree that it isn't the best practice to generate HTML from component, but the requirement is such here.